# splitting a drill file using regex

Tags: java, regex

i have a file here is it's dump

```
T01
X064900Y049200
X065900
X066900
X067900
X068900
X069900
T02
X062900Y048200
Y049200
Y050200
Y053700
X063900
X064900
X065900
X046350
```

I wan to split it's contents   by T*   "T* must be included" by using 
Java regex 
   here what i did i read file contents into `string parts`
then `String [] tools = parts.split("T\\d+");`

but it didn't work, what is the best regex to use .

Comment: Are each of the `X` terms on a separate line, separated by a line break of some kind?  What is your expected output?

Comment: You need to split on the _gaps between_ the stuff you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  yeah there is a line break between x terms

Comment: i think you mean `split("T\\d+")` with two backslash \\ instead of two slash

Comment: @YCF_L yeah backslash

Comment: what did you mean? with **yeah backslash**?

Comment: @YCF_L  two backslashes

Comment: then fix your question please

Comment: use `split("(?=T\\d)")`

Comment: @horcrux it doesn't work

Comment: @anubhava cause I need T01 nd what follows it and T02 and what follows it

Comment: @anubhava yeah but I need T01 and what follows it as a one string

Comment: So you want `T01
X064900Y049200
X065900
X066900
X067900
X068900
X069900` as one string?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/GY5UQb, what is wrong with horcrux's suggestion?

Comment: [`\s*(?=T\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LiCeQo/1) should work fine.

Comment: @anubhava thanks it worked ,but could you explain less than meaning here

Comment: `\s*` matches a whitespace and `(?=T\d)` is a lookahead that asserts we have `T` and some digit ahead of current position.

Comment: @anubhava  what is the benfits of ()  I tried to remove them but It doesn't work

Comment: That is lookahead syntax: See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accomplished even without the `split` method, but using a capturing group:

This is the Regex: `((?<=T)[^T]*)`

Answer (score 0):

Split at the letter "T".  The newline keeps the first line from being split.

```
String[] tools=parts.split("\n(?=T)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.I am assuming that you are expecting separate strings which starts with the letter 'T'.

```
package com.sujit;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Testt {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String txt="T01X064900Y049200X065900X066900X067900X068900X069900T02X062900Y048200Y049200Y050200Y053700X063900X064900X065900X046350";
            Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("T");
            String[] parts = ptn.split(txt);
            for(String p:parts){
                if(!p.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("T"+p);
                }               
            }
    }
}
```

Output:

T01X064900Y049200X065900X066900X067900X068900X069900
T02X062900Y048200Y049200Y050200Y053700X063900X064900X065900X046350